# How to Ignore Messages on Discord Python Bot for small specefic minutes?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi all Python Developers for Discord Py !
 currently i'm building a New Discord Bot for Delivering my Own product and i don't know how to stop Discord bot from receiving many messages at once ....
for instance my bot take message and deliver all messages from Same User unlimited time ( keeps on saving old message and processing it) , so what is the best idea to make discord bot ignore messages while python processing a Current Process ( write file or upload etc... ) or better yet to throw exception to all Other users messages?? and thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you post a small sample of the code you're working on to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your bot is sending messages based on an `on_message()` event, then you need to make sure you skip the messages from the bot itself, which, of course, will trigger the `on_message()` event.

`message.author` is the author of the message.
`client.user` is the bot.

Try something like this (bot will send message if the word "bot" is in the message):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if "bot" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Message from BotMcBot here')
```